# Show the full post by default in the flag queue

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flag-queue

The first thing I do for 99% of flags I review in the 10k flag queue is click the ">" so I can see the full, rendered post.

Seeing the mangled preview of a post with no formatting makes my eyes bleed and does *not* (in 99% of situations) give me enough info to review the post. We should be *encouraged* to review the full post before flagging a post; not being offered a cheap & easy way out like we currently are.

I propose that the full, rendered body of the post is *always* shown by default. I would like to see the ">" being reassigned to toggle the body of the *question* the answer belongs to (in the event the post is an answer), as it's not often I need to refer to the question to determine the validity of the flag.

Comment: There is *possibly* a counter-argument to be made that the more you show the less likely it is that people will read it, so they'll just say 'ooh, tldr - I guess it looks good'. But in general, yes, I agree with you that it should show the full text.